# Page does not change after file update/upload

Tags: php, fileupdate

I really need help on this one.
I am working on a site and made some changes on some lines, but after I uploaded it there were no changes happening. I have cleared my cache, even did ccleaner and a restart. Open the file again via ftp and the code is there but when I go to the site nothing has changed. I have also tried different browsers.

Sorry for bad English, but I really needed your help.

edit 1: i have tried deleting the file and i get 404 page. But when i uploaded it again, with the changed code, it display no changes at all again.
edit 2: i really think it's on the server side problem and any idea about it would be helpful, not some file being misplaced or something. i know i am working with the same file and put it on the right folder.

EDIT 3: SOLVED, the technical personnel said that the server is running eaccelerator and mtime was disabled and was causing the problem.

Comment: What FTP program are you using ? Have you tried WINSCP ?

Comment: Sounds like you're simply FTP-ing to the wrong place.

Comment: If you see that your new code is there by uploading then downloading the copy, chances are you're uploading the file to the wrong location. Try renaming the file and see if it still get served. If it does, you're not viewing the file you think you are changing.

Comment: To confirm that you are actually writing over the file that you think you are (and you are sure you have a copy of everything!), delete the file from the server, then try viewing that page in your browser.  If you don't see a 404 error, then you are copying the file to the wrong place.

Comment: @sh4nx0r i'm using FileZilla
have tried deleting the file and it showed 403 page in my sites case. uploaded it again and nothing have changed. the code is still correct but the page display still not the same.

Comment: @sh4nx0r also tried WINSCP but still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Correlate to a localhost (xampp or similar), i.e. if you don't see the same issue than you know it must be a transfer issue.  Divide and Conquer in this manner to troubleshoot.

Comment: unfortunately i can't get it to work locally. i did not create the site and i am newly hired to develop some changes.